How to detect screen resolution change in EXWM?
I use EXWM but noticed that changing resolution of display does not change resize of Emacs frames, windows and it's contents.
I've noticed that calling manually (exwm-xrandr-refresh) fixes this but how could I detect resolution change to call this function in some callback?

It is probably not a good idea to have Emacs running a perpetual function scanning for screen size changes -- the less stuff going on, the more responsive Emacs will be.  That being said, some functions that might be helpful, include, but are not limited to display-pixel-width and display-pixel-height, and checking frame parameters and frame geometry ...

Some events are registered at exwm-init time, so maybe all that's needed is registering whatever event is generated when resolution is changed. See exwm-randr.el and xcb-randr.el for details.
